# Is it possible to change the grid size in Quartus II schematic window?

Tags: schematics, quartus-ii

Having a schematic for the top level structure of design appears to be a good idea. I have a few schematic symbols that I want to edit. The signal name is too long and does not appear correctly in the autogenerated symbol for a design block.

When I try to edit the symbol, the grid size gets in the way. Can I make the grid size smaller in Quartus II schematic window?

Answer (score 1):

From the Help:

Quartus II Help v15.0 > Creating Designs > Using the Block Editor > Viewing Blocks and Symbols

On the Tools menu, click Options.

In the Category list, select Block/Symbol Editor.

In the Guideline spacing box, type or select the default guideline spacing for all new files.

To snap to the grid, turn on Snap to grid.

Click OK.

It worked OK when I tried it.

Comment: hmm It does not seem to change the grid to which the blocks snap, in anycase, I wanted to make the grid smaller. However, this does not seem to be possible at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think the grid can be made smaller.